# im using mongo and nodeJs Async returns an empty task when i use return. But console.log show me all the data

Tags: javascript

when i call the function .get returns an empty object. When i use console.log returns the database but when the function reach returns result is {}.

```js
let { connection, mongoose } = require("../../../config/mongodb");
let { Schema, model } = mongoose;
let { productosSchema } = require("../../../schemas/productos");
let productosSchemaModel = new Schema(productosSchema);
let Productos = new model("productos", productosSchemaModel);


class ProductosService {
  constructor(url) {
    this.url = url;
  }
  async getProds() {

    try {
      const allProds = await Productos.find({}).sort({ producto: 1   });
      return prods;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your variable name is `allProds`, not `prods`

Comment: Hey Lucas! I'm sorry, it's not clear where do you get the error.
It might be related to incorrect usage of async function (you have to await it, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

As [@CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) said, your variable name is `allProds`, not `prods`. Simply change the return from `return prods;` to `return allProds;` and it should work. See below for the complete code:

```js
const { mongoose } = require('../../../config/mongodb');
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;
const { productosSchema } = require('../../../schemas/productos');
const productosSchemaModel = new Schema(productosSchema);
const Productos = new model('productos', productosSchemaModel);

class ProductosService {
    constructor(url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    async getProds() {

        try {
            const allProds = await Productos.find({}).sort({
                producto: 1
            });
            return allProds;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```